# How can i generate HTML file with same code and save it into specific folder, using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to generate a html file in codeigniter with same ready code as below: and save it into folder and save the file path into db to echo this file path with an anchor tag.

For Example: I have multiple services Card with short info on homepage page, and every services are anchored (linked) with HTML Detail page of each services. e.g. 1st Service linked with services1.html file and 2nd Service linked with Services2.html and so on. When user click on services button the specific service page open within same homepage using javascript/ajax colorbox popup with out redirecting or changing page url. Now i want to generate services for homepage, from admin-side include its html detail file and image. how can i do this process please help how can perform this process in codeigniter. for more idea clearance you may check the team section of below template link:

> http://revolution2.boston.wp.themeforest.createit.pl

### HTML file Ready Code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
    <h2>Heading <span class="color-font light">Here</span></h2>
    <h3>CEO</h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="person-image">
            <img src="images/t1.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <h3>About Me</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis, turpis vel hendrerit interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci. Nam congue, pede vitae dapibus aliquet.</p>            
        <h3>Certifications</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis, turpis vel hendrerit interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci. Nam congue, pede vitae dapibus aliquet.</p>

        <h3>Socialise with me</h3>
        <ul class="social-links">
            <li><a class="fa fa-facebook fa-4x" href="#" onMouseOver="this.style.color = '#3B5998'" onMouseOut=" this.style.color='#ffffff' "></a></li>
            <li><a class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x" href="#" onMouseOver="this.style.color = '#33CCFF'" onMouseOut=" this.style.color='#ffffff' "></a></li>
            <li><a class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x" href="#" onMouseOver="this.style.color = '#DA3073'" onMouseOut=" this.style.color='#ffffff' "></a></li>
            <li><a class="fa fa-google-plus fa-4x" href="#" onMouseOver="this.style.color = '#dd4b39'" onMouseOut=" this.style.color='#ffffff' "></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a code writing service: that isn't Stack.

Comment: No i need just need hint how to create html file with sample code... and save in folder.. is this like image file or what?

Comment: It's like saving any other file. Just create/open a file, and write contents to it. There are so many examples on how to write to a file that this question seems like very little effort has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Using PHP [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function
2. Using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Thank You! for you kind support <3

Comment: Glad to help :-)